# How to configure java based configuration using

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration

Exeption:

HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/SecondBook_war/sample] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.20

What should i do to configure SpringMVC? Maybe someone knows where to find a guide on how to correctly configure the spring? And where you not just copy, but where it will be explained what to do

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/Views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return bean;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.scan("com.example");
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = sc.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class SampleController {
    @GetMapping("/sample")
    public String showForm() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem try to change your tomcat version, because the `javax` namespace is not supported in tomcat10.